# Is it possible to add support for additional OIDs in SNMPD (RHEL)

Tags: linux, redhat, snmp, snmpd, oid

I am trying to have my monitor poll the number of `ESTABLISHED` TCP sessions on a Linux server that is running **snmpd**.

The OID information I am trying to poll can be found [Here](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/tcp.html) .  The OID is specifically `.1.3.6.1.2.1.6.9`.  **snmpget** returns:

```
 TCP-MIB::tcpCurrEstab = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

I know this is not an authentication issue.  I am running simple and fairly unrestricted configs and have tested other OIDs.  I don't think this OID is supported on a RHEL6 system.

With that being said, is it possible to add support for OIDs so they can be polled?